# dynamically create a case statement for sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a list of tuples in python that I want to create a case statement sqlalchemy based on that.

Let's say the list of tuples is:
[('a', 5),('b', 6),('c', 7)]

I can construct the SQL statement like below:

```
xpr = case([(Mytable.name == 'a', Mytable.length >= 5),
            (Mytable.name == 'b', Mytable.length >= 6),
            (Mytable.name == 'c', Mytable.length >= 7)
            ])
```

But I like to make this automatically using a for loop over the list and create the case statement dynamically instead of manually adding codes to the case statement.

Comment: Instead of 'a', '5', 'b' etc you can directly use list indexing to take values from the list of tuple if that is what you need

Comment: `case([(Mytable.name == x, Mytable.length >= y) for x, y in [('a', 5),('b', 6),('c', 7)]])`

Comment: @IljaEverilä do you by chance know how I would go about adding an else case to this dynamically generated case statement?